# Testing Higher Order Components using jest and enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I created a test for a higher order component but whenever I run the test I get this error: `Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(ExampleComponent)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(ExampleComponent)".`

I think it may have something to do with the way I composed the HOC as an anonymous function where I can't export connect function but I'm not sure of how I could fix it. Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.

### HOCExample.js

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export default ComposedComponent => {
  class ExampleComponent extends PureComponent {
    //some logic here
    render() {
      return (
          <div style={{ marginTop: 80 }}>
            <ComposedComponent {...this.props} />
          </div>
        )
      );
    }
  }

  ExampleComponent.contextTypes = {
    test: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    example: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  };

  const mapStateToProps = ({ example }) => ({
    count: example.count,
  });

  const mapDispatchToProps = { getExampleCount };

  return connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
  )(ExampleComponent);
};
```

### HOCExample.test.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme;'
import { default as HOCExample } from '../HOCExample';

const TestComponent = () => <h1>Test</h1>

const ComponentRendered = HOCExample(TestComponent)

describe('HOCExample', () => {
  const props = {
    example: []
  };

  it('renders authorized component', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<ComponentRendered {...props} />);
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is solved as error message suggests, i.e. with `Provider`:

```
const wrapper = shallow(<Provider store={dummyStore}><ComponentRendered {...props} /></Provider>);
```

Where `dummyStore` is Redux store that conforms to the case, for example, has `example` property.

Answer (score 2):

You are not passing store down to the component you are testing.

The following article is a good resource in how to setup your test https://medium.com/@visualskyrim/test-your-redux-container-with-enzyme-a0e10c0574ec

redux-mock-store is helpful in mocking a store.

```
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
const createMockStore = configureMockStore();
const defaultState = {} // whatever you want the default store state to be
const store = createMockStore(defaultState);

//helper wrapper function
const giveStore = (component, store) => {
  const context = {
    store,
  };
  return shallow(component, { context });
};

const wrapper = giveStore(<ComponentRendered {...props} />, store);
```

You can refactor this to a separate helper file and make it reusable, such as passing more options into the giveStore helper and passing those props down to the component being tested (eg. history).